# How can I verify if a URLField is from a desired domain in Django?

Tags: django, forms

I have a URLField in my application form and I would like to check if the given URL is from www.domain.com.

Right now I'm using this solution in the clean method of the field, but I think that is not the best one...

```
    def clean_link(self):
    link = self.cleaned_data['link']
    if 'domain.com' not in link:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You only can add a domain.com URL.')

    return link
```

For example, if I enter http://www.thisismydomain.com would be correct. Any other solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: basically you are doing regular expressions, so any of many similar approaches is valid. You will probably want to force your input to be lowercase "link.lower()", since domains are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might want to have a look at the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module, to avoid misses like

```
>>> 'good_domain.com' in 'http://evildomain.com/mylink#good_domain.com'
True
```

Comment: Thank you! I love to dive in the Python and Django documentation, but when you don't know what are you looking for is quite difficult to find something!

Comment: @David - also note, if you can (i.e., if the rule is meant to be universally enforced for the field), use a validator (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#validators), rather than coding this into an admin view, or a form's clean method.

Comment: Until this moment I didn't have time to play with urlparse and it's awesome, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to use some kind of regular expressions (regex) in your `clean_link` method. I don't know about it in detail, but the [urparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module mentioned by @second may be good, or you can just use the [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module. Your current overall strategy seems fine though.